# Xamarin, Android: Change size of linear Layout programmatically

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

here is my code:

```
        linlay = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_profile);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams _params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (500, 500);
        linlay.LayoutParameters = _params;
```

So, in my xml, there is a linearlayout with a height 0f 200.
Now, in the programcode I need to change the height to 500.
But it crashes on the last bit of code:

```
    linlay.LayoutParameters = _params;
```

Why is that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the solution:
appearently, the layoutparams have to be of the parent. in my case this was a framelayout.
dont get it either but its working now.

```
        linlay = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_profile);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams _params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
            (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, 
            (Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / 3));
        linlay.LayoutParameters = _params;
```